# Can a single sonarQube project be linked to multiple git repos?

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

Our company shares sonarQube (version 7) between many teams and the sonarQube admins created a single sonarqube project for my team. Our team has many un-related projects in Git which use Jenkins (version 2.69) pipelines to build. Can we realistically use a single sonarQube project to contain multiple git projects? I tried to use modules but when I build a project, the previous module's report is erased and replaced by the new module's report (they use different project names but the same key).

It seems the sonarQube modules config is meant to organize modules within a SINGLE git repo. Anyone do anything similar?

Comment: Each SonarQube project is identified by an unique [project key](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Settings). if you use the same project key for different setups your old results will be replaced. If you are only allowed to use a single project you must analyse all your projects at the same time.